# Delegated "template" binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, user-interface, data-binding, web, knockout.js

## Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA5k9/

So I want to create a shortcut for the template binding like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shortcut = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var data = valueAccessor();
            var nextValueAccessor = function () {
                return  { name: 'someTemplate', data: data };
            };
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.call(this, element, nextValueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="shortcut: 'Hey!'"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="someTemplate">
   <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</script>
```

The "someTemplate" template is defined. It just doesn't work without saying anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is essentially that you are not calling the `update` function of the template binding.  You may find it easier to use a slightly different approach to wrap the binding though, so that you only have to use the `init` function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shortcut = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, {
                template: function() {
                    return {
                        name: 'someTemplate',
                        data: valueAccessor()
                    };
                }
            }, bindingContext)

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RXu9t/

If you are still using KO 2.x, then you would want to use `ko.applyBindingsToNode` instead like:

```
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            template: {
                name: 'someTemplate',
                data: valueAccessor()
            }
        }, bindingContext);
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/79yG8/